# Which Mac Mini is the earliest able to run Yosemite?

Tags: macos, mac-mini

I plan to buy a used Mac Mini, my only requirement is to be able to run on in Yosemite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/:

> These Mac models are compatible with OS X Yosemite:
>
> - iMac (Mid 2007 or newer)
> - MacBook (Late 2008 Aluminum, or Early 2009 or newer)
> - MacBook Pro (Mid/Late 2007 or newer)
> - MacBook Air (Late 2008 or newer)
> - **Mac mini (Early 2009 or newer)**
> - Mac Pro (Early 2008 or newer)
> - Xserve (Early 2009)